# awk to return percentage by day of the week

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk, csv

So I have a dataset of flights in a CSV file and I want to get a percentage of flights delayed (column 6) ordered by day. 0 is for not delayed and 1 is for delayed 15 or more minutes.

Input:

```
DAY_OF_MONTH,"DAY_OF_WEEK","ORIGIN","DEST","DEP_TIME","DEP_DEL15","CANCELLED","DIVERTED","DISTANCE"
1,Tuesday,ORD,GRB,1003,0.00,0.00,0.00,322.248
1,Tuesday,TUL,ORD,1027,0.00,0.00,0.00,1083.42
1,Tuesday,EWR,TYS,1848,0.00,0.00,0.00,1168.61
```

Output:

```
Weekday, % delayed, delayed, total flights
Tuesday,0.00,0,3
```

The dataset actually has a lot of rows and has every day of a month and all its flights, so that wouldn't be the actual output.

Someone helped me come up with:

```
#!/bin/awk
BEGIN { FS = OFS = "," }
FNR > 1 { total[$2]++; if ($6) delay[$2]++ }
END {
    print "\"weekday\"", "\"percentage_delayed\"", "\"delayed\"", "\"total_flights\""
    for ( day in total ) { print day, delay[day] / total[day] * 100, delay[day], total[day]}

}
```

But when I save this to an awk file and try to execute it with: [image: Terminal Output]

Comment: You have to change shebang to `#!/bin/awk -f` but the script does not produce output you posted in your question.

Comment: Posted as Panri93 on 21-May-2021 in https://community.unix.com/t/performing-operations-with-awk/382816, and closed as undeclared homework. You should learn from previous answers, not just contaminate a different site.

Comment: Homework questions are allowed here - although it's recommended (and polite!) to say so if it's not completely obvious because some people don't want to answer homework at all, or prefer to give hints and tutorial-style help rather than a complete answer.   This series of questions has always seemed like obvious homework to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `#!/bin/awk` you're telling awk to run using the **name** of the file containing the script as the script rather than the **contents** of the file containing the script. It's like writing:

```
awk './delayed_by_day_jan20.awk'
```

instead of:

```
awk -f './delayed_by_day_jan20.awk'
```

Just like specifying a file containing an awk script on the command line, you have to use `-f` in a shebang too to tell awk to open the file name it's passed (i.e. the name of the current script file) and use it's contents as the awk script to interpret.

Having said that....

Consider every command you write in Unix to be just a command. It doesn't matter if that command is written in awk, perl, shell or anything else - it should be named based on what it **does**, not how it's implemented. Given that, you should never have commands that end in `.awk` or `.sh` or `.perl` or anything else that indicates the language they're written in so that, among other things, you can re-implement any command you wrote in awk to perl or vice-versa without having to go through all of your other commands that call that command to change them. So your command name should be `delayed_by_day_jan20`, not `delayed_by_day_jan20.awk`.

Also, others disagree with this because they like to use an editor that understands awk syntax, but IMO you should never use a shebang to call awk, just use the shebang to call whatever shell you use and then simply call awk inside your shell script just like you'd call it from the command line. That will greatly reduce complexity of your scripts for those extremely common cases where it's useful to do most of the job in awk but also parts of it in shell, e.g. validating existence of input files, creating temp files, setting traps, separating command arguments into awk variable assignments vs awk arguments, etc., etc. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/61002754/1745001 and [google "awk shebang"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22awk+shebang%22) for more information on the issues.

Here's how to write your shell script:

```
$ cat delayed_by_day_jan20
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk '
BEGIN { FS = OFS = "," }
FNR > 1 { total[$2]++; if ($6) delay[$2]++ }
END {
    print "\"weekday\"", "\"percentage_delayed\"", "\"delayed\"", "\"total_flights\""
    for ( day in total ) {
        printf "%s,%0.2f,%d,%d\n", day, delay[day] / total[day] * 100, delay[day], total[day]
    }
}
' "${@:--}"
```

```
$ ./delayed_by_day_jan20 file
"weekday","percentage_delayed","delayed","total_flights"
Tuesday,0.00,0,3
```

Now just fix your awk script to do whatever it is you want it to do if that's not it and ask a new question if you run into trouble doing that.